# iis windows authentication web api and signalr

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7, signalr, windows-authentication

I Have to different servers one for web api and the other is for push notifications(signalR). I am hosting both on iis7, both are working fine independently but when the api is trying to connect to the push server (as a signalrClient) I get 401 Unauthorized response. Both the api and the push are running by the same user, both have kerberos authentication. 
When I allow anonymuse in my push server it works perfectly. Unfortentally it can't be anonymose.
Thak you

Comment: Starting from ASP.NET 2.0, you need to learn what is delegation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Enable Windows authentication, Impersonation and disable rest in both the app.[image]

here is the web.config code:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: I could not make it work .. I am using this with kerberose it may be related?